# variable de entorno y uso en virtualenv

Tags: python, base-de-datos, mongodb, virtualenv, python-3.8

Estoy siguiendo un curso de MongoDB con Python pero no encuentro solución a crear una variable de entorno para utilizar los datos y conectarme a la base de datos en línea de MongoDB Atlas. Estaba tratando de buscar información pero no me queda muy claro el uso de dichas variables, pues lo único que pude encontrar el uso de la librería de Python `dotenv`, pero no me queda muy claro cómo es que debería usarla.

Dejo aquí un poco lo que mas o menos tengo de idea para el uso:

```py
import dotenv
import sys 
import os 

dotenv.load_dotenv()

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    nivel = sys.argv[1]
    if nivel.upper == 'PASS_MONGODB':
        passw = os.getenv('PASS_MONGODB')
    
    print(f"trabajando con {nivel}, password: {passw}")
```

Pero al yo querer utilizarla me dice que la variable no ha sido declarada.

Probé de esta otra manera e igual no me funciona

```py
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
nivel = sys.argv[1]
    if nivel.upper == 'PASS_MONGODB':
        passw = os.getenv('PASS_MONGODB')
    else:
        raise SystemExit("Datos Desconocidos")
    
    print(f"trabajando con {nivel}, password: {passw}")
```

Comment: ¿Podrías identar correctamente el código? Así mismo, indica cómo estás invocando este script desde la línea de comandos.

Comment: ok yo estoy creando una app para aprender el uso de mongoDB y tengo problemas  con las variables de entorno ya que he leido por ahi que poner las credenciales del usuario de la BD en el codigo de la aplicacion esta mal entonces lei sobre dotenv y entendi que puedes crear como una archivo de variables de entorno del proyecto para asi guardar mis datos como usuario y contraseña en este archivo y solo leer dichas variables para la conexion ahorita te comento el codigo de mis dos archivos y un poco de mi logica

Answer (score 0):

.env

```
USER = "username"
PASS_MONGO = "password"
```

config.py

```
import dotenv
import sys 
import os 

dotenv.load_dotenv()

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    nivel = sys.argv[1]
    if nivel.upper == 'PASS_MONGODB':
        passw = os.getenv('PASS_MONGODB')
    else:
        raise SystemExit("Datos Desconocidos")
    
    print(f"trabajando con {nivel}, password: {passw}")
```

pero asi al yo querer imprimir las variables no me las muestra me dice datos desconocidos
y este archivo lo estoy invocando desde mi archivo main.py o si me podrias decir como es la forma correcta para crear variables de entorno

Comment: El área de respuesta es sólo para respuestas, si vas a agregar información debes editar tu pregunta. Esto no es un hilo tipo twitter. Una sola pregunta y muchas posibles respuestas. Por favor agrega esta información a tu pregunta y elimina esta respuesta ya que no es una respuesta. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: hola muchas gracias soy nuevo en esta plataforma y no sabia esto que se debia editar la pregunta